# Permissions: How to deny an app Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: security, permissions, photos, intents

As the admin of my android device, I'd like to configure the device to return a permission denied error to all apps that request `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` by default, unless I explicitly give it permission to make that call.

I had an issue where an app made an [Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) call recently, which popped-up my picture gallery. I was attempting to do the "go back" gesture, but--by mistake--I tapped on one of the images. The result? **A very sensitive photo got uploaded to the public Internet**. It was a photo that I *really* didn't want anyone to see..

Unfortunately, user-errors happens. Until the day I die, I'm sure that I will continue to make input/gesture mis-taps. What I need is better protection from this at a permissions-level.

I checked the app's permissions, but it has none. It can't, for example, access my phone's storage.

What I want to do is further lock-down the apps on my phone such that apps are immediately returned some `Permission Denied` error when trying to initiate an `Intent` for which they haven't been added to the allowlist for that intent.

How can I deny an app permission to initiate `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`?